# How to Cross Compile for different hardwares

Tags: c++, performance, vectorization, cross-compiling

I have a Panel PC (Intel i7 with 2 cores) which runs 64-bit CentOS 7. I am not allowed to compile programs in this Panel PC. Hence I developed some C++ programs on a 64-bit RHEL 7 Desktop machine (Intel i7 with 16 cores) and ran it on the Panel PC. When I run such programs, due to the compatibility of RHEL and CentOS, the programs runs. But I know that the optimizations such as vectorizations will be specific to the Desktop machines where the program was build. When I port it to the Panel PC, it may not be optimum instructions. Do I need to cross-compile to get the performance? If so how can I get the required parameters which are optimum for the target platform (here Panel PC)?

Comment: Targeting a slightly different flavor of Intel x86_64 doesn't count as cross compiling. Research the optimization flags of the compiler, see if you can target specifically the CPU of the Panel PC. Before you do that, make sure you have to optimize in the first place. Is it really that slow?

Comment: Personally I find cross-compiling to be a pain and more trouble than its worth. *I* find it easier to just spin up virtual machines with the target system and then do native compiles there. If needed more than once or twice, add such VMs to your CI system - don't just do it manually.

Comment: find the architecture of your target machine and pass the appropriate `-march` flag to gcc